# when running my flex 4.5 mobile application its giving a bank screen

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flex4.5

I am working on Adobe Flex 4.5 mobile application. But sometimes when I am trying to run the application its giving a blank screen as output. Initially I restart my machine then the problem was solved. But the problem has again started. I have reinstalled the flash builder 4.5 but the same thing is happening. Initially, it ran properly but then again giving a blank output.

How to solve this?